# dojo 1.7 IE9 widget function call not triggering

Tags: dojo, widget, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to add a button to a custom pallete to call a function "uiFileInputDlg" which is in the workspace that uses the widget. The upbtn appears on the pallete, but it is not triggering the DoUpload function which is connected in postcreate to then call on "uiFileInputDlg".
works flawlessly in firefox.
we're user dojo 1.7.2

-----------THE TEMPLATE-------------------------

```
<div class="dijitInline dijitColorPalette">
    <div class="dijitColorPaletteInner" data-dojo-attach-point="divNode" role="grid" tabIndex="${tabIndex}">
    </div>    
    <button type="button" id="upbtn"
        data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" 
        data-dojo-props="id:'upbtn'" 
        data-dojo-attach-point="btnUpNode">
        Upload New Image
    </button>
</div>
```

-------------------------THE WIDGET--------------------------

//dojo.provide("meemli.UploadPalette");
define([    'dojo/_base/declare',
            'dijit/_WidgetBase',
            'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
            'dojo/i18n!dijit/nls/common',
            'dojo/text!./templates/UploadPalette.html',
            'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin',
            'dojo/_base/lang'
        ],
        function(declare, w, t, i18n, template, witm, lang){
            console.log('meemli.UploadPalette: Requiring dijit/nls/common.js INSTEAD OF dojo/nls/common' + i18n.invalidMessage);

```
    return declare("meemli.UploadPalette",
    [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated],
    {
    // summary: A keyboard accessible color-picking widget
    // description:
    //  Grid showing various colors, so the user can pick a certain color
    //  Can be used standalone, or as a popup.
    //
    // example:
    // |    <div dojoType="dijit.ColorPalette"></div>
    //
    // example:
    // |    var picker = new dijit.ColorPalette({ },srcNode);
    // |    picker.startup();
    //
    // defaultTimeout: Number
    //      number of milliseconds before a held key or button becomes typematic
    defaultTimeout: 500,

    // timeoutChangeRate: Number
    //      fraction of time used to change the typematic timer between events
    //      1.0 means that each typematic event fires at defaultTimeout intervals
    //      < 1.0 means that each typematic event fires at an increasing faster rate
    timeoutChangeRate: 0.90,

    // palette: String
    //      Size of grid, either "7x10" or "3x4".
    palette: "3x3",

    //_value: String
    //      The value of the selected color.
    value: null,

    //_currentFocus: Integer
    //      Index of the currently focused color.
    _currentFocus: 0,

    // _xDim: Integer
    //      This is the number of colors horizontally across.
    _xDim: null,

    // _yDim: Integer
    ///     This is the number of colors vertically down.
    _yDim: null,

    // _palettes: Map
    //      This represents the value of the colors.
    //      The first level is a hashmap of the different arrays available
    //      The next two dimensions represent the columns and rows of colors.
    _palettes: {
        "3x3": [],
        "3x2": ["/images/icons/1.png", "/images/icons/2.png", "/images/icons/3.png","/images/icons/4.png", "/images/icons/5.png", "/images/icons/6.png"]
    },

    // _imagePaths: Map
    //      This is stores the path to the palette images
//  _imagePaths: {
//      "3x3": dojo.moduleUrl("dijit", "templates/icons3x3.png")
//  },

    // _paletteCoords: Map
    //      This is a map that is used to calculate the coordinates of the
    //      images that make up the palette.
    _paletteCoords: {
        "leftOffset": 3, "topOffset": 3,
        "cWidth": 50, "cHeight": 50

    },

    // templatePath: String
    //      Path to the template of this widget.
//  templateString: dojo.cache("meemli", "templates/UploadPalette.html"),
    templateString: template,

    // _paletteDims: Object
    //      Size of the supported palettes for alignment purposes.
    _paletteDims: {
        "3x3": {"width": "156px", "height": "156px"}, // 48*3 + 3px left/top border + 3px right/bottom border...
        "3x2": {"width": "156px", "height": "109px"} // 48*3 + 3px left/top border + 3px right/bottom border...
    },

    // tabIndex: String
    //      Widget tabindex.
    maxCols: 3,
    tabIndex: "0",
    _curIndex: 0,

    DoUpload: function(){
        alert('hello');
        uiFileInputDlg(); // function out in the workspace
    },

    _addImage: function(url) {
        row = Math.floor(this._curIndex / this.maxCols);
        col = this._curIndex - (row * this.maxCols);
        this._curIndex++;
        this._yDim = Math.floor(this._curIndex / this.maxCols);
        this._xDim = this._curIndex - (row * this.maxCols);

        var imgNode = dojo.doc.createElement("img");
        imgNode.src = url;
        //imgNode.style.height = imgNode.style.width =  "48px";

        var cellNode = dojo.doc.createElement("span");
        cellNode.appendChild(imgNode);
        cellNode.connectionRefs = new Array();
        dojo.forEach(["Dijitclick", "MouseEnter", "Focus", "Blur"], function(handler) {
            cellNode.connectionRefs.push(this.connect(cellNode, "on" + handler.toLowerCase(), "_onCell" + handler));
        }, this);

        this.divNode.appendChild(cellNode);

        var cellStyle = cellNode.style;
        cellStyle.top = this._paletteCoords.topOffset + (row * this._paletteCoords.cHeight) + "px";
        cellStyle.left = this._paletteCoords.leftOffset + (col * this._paletteCoords.cWidth) + "px";
        cellStyle.height = this._paletteCoords.cHeight + "px";
        cellStyle.width = this._paletteCoords.cWidth + "px";
        // console.debug( "tlhw: " + cellStyle.top + ", " + cellStyle.left + ", " + cellStyle.height + ", " + cellStyle.width );

        // adjust size when the bits come...
//      this.xh = this.xw = "32px";
//console.log('this.xh => ' + this.xh);     
        dojo.connect( imgNode,"onload", this, function() {
//console.log('IN: CONNECT...this.xh => ' + this.xh);       
            this.xh = imgNode.height;
            this.xw = imgNode.width;
            this.xh = (this.xh==0) ? this.xh="32px" : (this.xh + "");
            this.xw = (this.xw==0) ? this.xw="32px" : (this.xw + "");
//          var h = parseInt( this.xh );
//          var w = parseInt( this.xw );
            var hArr = this.xh.split('p');
            var wArr = this.xw.split('p');
            var h =hArr[0];
            var w = wArr[0];

            var THUMBNAIL_MAX_WIDTH = 50;
            var THUMBNAIL_MAX_HEIGHT = 50;

            var hLim = Math.min(THUMBNAIL_MAX_HEIGHT, this._paletteCoords.cHeight);
            var wLim = Math.min(THUMBNAIL_MAX_WIDTH, this._paletteCoords.cWidth);

            var scale = 1.0;

            if( h > hLim || w > wLim ) {
                if( h / w < 1.0 ) { // width is bigger than height
                    scale = wLim / w;
                }
                else {
                    scale = hLim / h;
                }
            }

            imgNode.style.height = (scale * h) + "px";
            imgNode.style.width = (scale * w) + "px";
            console.debug( imgNode.src + ' loaded.'
                + "old: h " + h + ", w " + w + ", scale " + scale
                + ". new: h " + imgNode.style.height + ", w " + imgNode.style.width );
        } );
        if(dojo.isIE){
            // hack to force event firing in IE
            // image quirks doc'd in dojox/image/Lightbox.js :: show: function.
//          imgNode.src = imgNode.src;
        }

        dojo.attr(cellNode, "tabindex", "-1");
        dojo.addClass(cellNode, "imagePaletteCell");
        dijit.setWaiRole(cellNode, "gridcell");
        cellNode.index = this._cellNodes.length;
        this._cellNodes.push(cellNode);

    },

    _clearImages: function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < this._cellNodes.length; i++) {
            this._cellNodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(this._cellNodes[i]);
        }
        this._currentFocus = 0;
        this._curIndex = 0;
        this._yDim = 0;
        this._xDim = 0;
        this._cellNodes = [];
    },

    setImages: function(imageList) {
        this._clearImages();
        for(var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
            this._addImage(imageList[i]);
        }
    },

    postCreate: function(){
        // A name has to be given to the colorMap, this needs to be unique per Palette.
        dojo.mixin(this.divNode.style, this._paletteDims[this.palette]);
//      this.imageNode.setAttribute("src", this._imagePaths[this.palette]);
        this.domNode.style.position = "relative";
        this._cellNodes = [];   
        this.setImages(this._palettes[this.palette]);
        this.connect(this.divNode, "onfocus", "_onDivNodeFocus");
        this.connect(this.btnUpNode, "onclick", "DoUpload");

        // Now set all events
        // The palette itself is navigated to with the tab key on the keyboard
        // Keyboard navigation within the Palette is with the arrow keys
        // Spacebar selects the color.
        // For the up key the index is changed by negative the x dimension.     

        var keyIncrementMap = {
            UP_ARROW: -this._xDim,
            // The down key the index is increase by the x dimension.   
            DOWN_ARROW: this._xDim,
            // Right and left move the index by 1.
            RIGHT_ARROW: 1,
            LEFT_ARROW: -1
        };
        for(var key in keyIncrementMap){
            this._connects.push(dijit.typematic.addKeyListener(this.domNode,
                {keyCode:dojo.keys[key], ctrlKey:false, altKey:false, shiftKey:false},
                this,
                function(){
                    var increment = keyIncrementMap[key];
                    return function(count){ this._navigateByKey(increment, count); };
                }(),
                this.timeoutChangeRate, this.defaultTimeout));
        }
    },

    focus: function(){
        // summary:
        //      Focus this ColorPalette.  Puts focus on the first swatch.
        this._focusFirst();
    },

    onChange: function(url, hsz, wsz){
        // summary:
        //      Callback when a image is selected.
        // url, hsz, wsz, strings
        //      height and width string .
//      console.debug("img selected: "+url);
    },

    _focusFirst: function(){
        this._currentFocus = 0;
        var cellNode = this._cellNodes[this._currentFocus];
        window.setTimeout(function(){dijit.focus(cellNode);}, 0);
    },

    _onDivNodeFocus: function(evt){
        // focus bubbles on Firefox 2, so just make sure that focus has really
        // gone to the container
        if(evt.target === this.divNode){
            this._focusFirst();
        }
    },

    _onFocus: function(){
        // while focus is on the palette, set its tabindex to -1 so that on a
        // shift-tab from a cell, the container is not in the tab order
        dojo.attr(this.divNode, "tabindex", "-1");
    },

    _onBlur: function(){
        this._removeCellHighlight(this._currentFocus);
        // when focus leaves the palette, restore its tabindex, since it was
        // modified by _onFocus().
        dojo.attr(this.divNode, "tabindex", this.tabIndex);
    },

    _onCellDijitclick: function(/*Event*/ evt){
        // summary:
        //      Handler for click, enter key & space key. Selects the color.
        // evt:
        //      The event.
        var target = evt.currentTarget;
        if (this._currentFocus != target.index){
            this._currentFocus = target.index;
            window.setTimeout(function(){dijit.focus(target);}, 0);
        }
        this._selectColor(target);
        dojo.stopEvent(evt);
    },

    _onCellMouseEnter: function(/*Event*/ evt){
        // summary:
        //      Handler for onMouseOver. Put focus on the color under the mouse.
        // evt:
        //      The mouse event.
        var target = evt.currentTarget;
        window.setTimeout(function(){dijit.focus(target);}, 0);
    },

    _onCellFocus: function(/*Event*/ evt){
        // summary:
        //      Handler for onFocus. Removes highlight of
        //      the color that just lost focus, and highlights
        //      the new color.
        // evt:
        //      The focus event.
        this._removeCellHighlight(this._currentFocus);
        this._currentFocus = evt.currentTarget.index;
        dojo.addClass(evt.currentTarget, "imagePaletteCellHighlight");
    },

    _onCellBlur: function(/*Event*/ evt){
        // summary:
        //      needed for Firefox 2 on Mac OS X
        this._removeCellHighlight(this._currentFocus);
    },

    _removeCellHighlight: function(index){
        dojo.removeClass(this._cellNodes[index], "imagePaletteCellHighlight");
    },

    _selectColor: function(selectNode){ 
        // summary:
        //      This selects a color. It triggers the onChange event
        // area:
        //      The area node that covers the color being selected.
        var img = selectNode.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
        this.onChange(this.value = img.src, this.xh, this.xw);
    },

    _navigateByKey: function(increment, typeCount){
        // summary:
        //      This is the callback for typematic.
        //      It changes the focus and the highlighed color.
        // increment:
        //      How much the key is navigated.
        // typeCount:
        //      How many times typematic has fired.

        // typecount == -1 means the key is released.
        if(typeCount == -1){ return; }

        var newFocusIndex = this._currentFocus + increment;
        if(newFocusIndex < this._cellNodes.length && newFocusIndex > -1)
        {
            var focusNode = this._cellNodes[newFocusIndex];
            focusNode.focus();
        }
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Update

```
this.connect(this.btnUpNode, "onclick", "DoUpload");
```

to be

```
this.connect(this.btnUpNode, "onClick", "DoUpload");
```

`onclick` is a dom event, `onClick` is a dijit event.  Since you are using a dijit button you want to use the latter.